# Type'()' cannot conform to 'View' - Geocoder

Tags: swiftui, geocoder

Most examples online were using UIKit so I could not find much help. I got a function from apple, but I'm not too sure how to call it. I'm completely new to swiftUI so pardon me if the question this question is silly. The following code below its supposed to get convert an address string to coordinates but no matter what I do I keep getting the error: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'

```
var body: some View {
    getCoordinate(addressString: some address) { coordinate, error in
      if error != nil {
        return
      } else {
        Print("resulting coordinate = ((coordinate.latitude),(coordinate.longitude))")
      }
    }
}
func getCoordinate( addressString : String,
        completionHandler: @escaping(CLLocationCoordinate2D, NSError?) -> Void ) {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(addressString) { (placemarks, error) in
        if error == nil {
            if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {
                let location = placemark.location!

                completionHandler(location.coordinate, nil)
                return
            }
        }

        completionHandler(kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid, error as NSError?)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SwiftUI works in a different way. Don't do *controller* stuff in a SwiftUI view. Add a view model, do the calculations there and notify the view to refresh

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I meant to type could not above. I am not using any UIKit stuff in this view. Any further ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: You have to return a SwiftUI `View` in the body of the view. `geocoder.geocodeAddressString` returns nothing (aka `()`). This is what the error says.

Comment: Ah I see, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: As I said *Add a view model, do the calculations there and notify the view to refresh*. A view model is an extra class conforming to `ObservableObject`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I'm still at a complete loss did you mean something like this? If so where do I go from here?

`class ViewModel: ObservableObject {function here }`

Comment: Please read or watch a tutorial. A pretty good one is  [100 days of SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100/swiftui)

Comment: These are good as well: [Apple's SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) & [Stanford's CS193P](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu)

Comment: The `View`'s `body` is only for SwiftUI `View`s and is synchronous. So far everything in your `body` is something other than a SwiftUI `View`. To make it simpler unless the user is meant to see it on their screen or touch it the code should be somewhere else SwiftUI is for User Interaction not for the actual coordinate or geocoded request.

Comment: Hi thanks for the rapid replies. I have finally got it working using a class.